# Submitting a New Scope for Approval on Facebook App Verification

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have an existing app that allows users to create and share live videos on their personal profile. I tested this app in developer mode, submitted it for verification and the approval team could use their test users to demo the functionality and then approve the app.

It's now three months later and I want to update the app to allow the same functionality for the user's pages. So I add the scope *pages_manage_posts* to my app review and test on a separate testing app in developer mode.

When I use test users on the live app though, myself and the test users can't use the scope that's not yet been approved, even on Pages the business owns. Because of this the app reviewers can't testing the functionality and won't approve the new permission.

```
(#200) If posting to a group, requires app being installed in the group, and either publish_to_groups permission with user token, or both manage_pages and publish_pages permission with page token; If posting to a page, requires both manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with sufficient administrative permission
```

How can you test and approve new scopes on an existing live Facebook App? I'm stuck in a loop/

Comment: The reviewers have accounts available, that are able to circumvent these restrictions. What was the exact feedback they gave you?

Answer (score 0):

I was instructed to use Facebook Test Apps. Here's how I did it:

1. I created a test app with the instructions here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps/
2. I updated my app so that when logged in with the test user the Facebook API would switch to the app id and secret token from the new test app
3. Re-submitted. I'll see if that helps